# how do I execute ruby code with access to the Database before rails application begins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I will like to know how can I execute some ruby code just before the rails application begins. I need
to have access to database and be able to set some variables for the views to access.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to create initializer under `./config/initializers` directory with necessary code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use activerecord alone to set some constants.

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2005/10/3/easy-activerecord-scripts

Answer (score 1):

I think, a better approach is to not go with database, but create a configuration file, say, **app_config.yml** in your **application_root/config** folder, and then load it using the following line in the **environment.rb** file.

```
APP_SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/app_config.yml")
```

Your **app_config.yml** file looks like this

```
appname: something.com
appsettings: something...
appvar: something...
```

You can access these config variables from anywhere in your application as:

```
APP_SETTINGS['appname']
```

and so on.

This **yml** file is loaded at the time the rails server is started. Hence, if you make any changes to this file, your server should be restarted.

Comment: I need to access to the database to create the config file, it will be base on some of the data.

Comment: You can write your database access code in application.rb, which is the main entry point to your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up something that the views can use right away, try sticking the code in `db/seeds.rb`. That's where you should put any creation of objects that you might need, like reference data (e.g populate a Countries table or set up some user Roles).

It is automatically run when the DB is reset, or through `rake db:reset`.